# Creating a table dynamicaly with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, creation

I am learning Hibernate ORM(v. 3 ) now and I've a got a question.
I have a table called USERS, created with annotations :

```
package com.hibernatedb.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"USER_LOGIN", "USER_EMAIL"})})
public class User {

@Column(name = "USER_LOGIN", length=80, nullable=false)
private String login;

@Column(name = "USER_PASS", length=80, nullable=false)
private String password;
    @Column(name = "USER_EMAIL", length=80, nullable=false)
private String email;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable=false)
private Long id;

...
// some getters and setters, toString() and other stuff
... 
}
```

And a Product entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_NAME"})})
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
private long id;

@Column(name="PRODUCT_NAME", length=85, nullable=false)
private String name;

@Column(name="PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION", columnDefinition="mediumtext", length=1000)
private String description;

@Column(name="PRODUCT_COST", nullable=false)
private double cost;
```

So my question is : How can a create a table called like "USER +

> User.getId()

BUYS", which contains a 2 foreign keys (USER_ID and PRODUCT_ID) for user in entity (table record) "User" ***without* raw SQL table creation**, but using Hibernate annotations or XML mapping.So i want to have something like

```
public class TransactionEntityBulider() {
public TransactionEntityBulder(User user)    
     // something that build me "USER + User.getId() BUYS" table and
}
public TransactionEntity getEntity() {
     // something that return a "USER + User.getId() BUYS" table entity
}
```

Also i would like to see some another ways to solve my problem.

Comment: Do you mean you want create table USER_BUYS (which contains USER_ID and PRODUCT_ID)?

Comment: No, i wanted to create a table for each record in table USERS with name like "USER"+User.getId()+"BUYS". And these tables will contain USER_ID and PRODUCT_ID foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think hibernate is not done for that kind of usage, because you would have to use dynamic mappings.  Hibernate provide ways to specify mapping statically (xml and annotations).

I suggest you modify your approach.  It normally should not be harmfull to have all the "USER_BUY" in the same table.  Example :

```
@Entity
public class User { 
...
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
    List<UserBuys> buys = new ArrayList<UserBuys>(); 
...
}

@Entity
public class Product { ... }

@Entity
public class UserBuys {
  ...

  @ManyToOne
  Product product;

  @ManyToOne
  User user;
}
```